# Can objective function and gradient be unlimited in reinforcement learning?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, deep-rl, gradient-descent, policy-gradients

I'm looking at an example where they define a policy $\pi_\theta(a_t|s_t)\sim \mathcal{N}(ks_t, \sigma)$, where $a_t$ and $s_t$ are action and state, while $\theta=(k,\sigma)$ are the parameters of the policy. Now I take the sampled approximation of the objective gradient for a policy gradient algorithm (like REINFORCE)

$\bigtriangledown_\theta J(\theta) \simeq \frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \left[\sum_{t=1}^T \bigtriangledown_\theta log\pi_\theta(a_t^i|s_t^i) \sum_{t=1}^T r(s_t^i,a_t^i) \right] $,

where $log\pi_\theta(a_t^i|s_t^i) =-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}(ks_t^i-a_t^i)^2+const$

and $\bigtriangledown_\theta log\pi_\theta(a_t^i|s_t^i) =\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial k} \\ \frac{\partial J(\theta)}{\partial \sigma}
\end{bmatrix} = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
  -\frac{s_t^i}{\sigma^2}(ks_t^i-a_t^i)\\ \frac{1}{\sigma^3}(ks_t^i-a_t^i)^2
\end{bmatrix}$

in the example they say that the optimal solution is $k=-1,\sigma=0$, but as i get closer to the solution, the objective and the gradient get bigger and goes to infinity. I believe this is a problem, isn't it? Ok, maybe it's a problem only in practices but not in theory... however, I wonder if we can always fall in this situation, since we don't decide the objective function